# Error sending email via SMTP in C#, Does this still work in 2017?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

Having researched the issue extensively especially applying recommendations from similar issues on stackoverflow, the below code still returns error ""System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: connection rejected at....""

```
        try
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("demo77377@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com"));
            mail.Subject = "TEST";
            mail.Body = "This is a test mail from C# program";

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("demo77377@gmail.com", "AABBCCDDEE1!","gmail.com");
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Timeout = 10000;                    
                //
                smtp.Send(mail);
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
```

I have done everything possible 
On Client> I have alternated smtp properties (permutation) etc 
On Server> I have made gmail account less secure, I have disabled captcha etc

I observed that similar issues on stackoverflow were mostly dated over 3years ago and thus, is it possible that gmail no longer supports this SMTP method via C#, likewise has it been deprecated in favor of gmail API

Also, please find provided in code, original password supplied for the gmail account, in order to confirm if this issue is general or isolated to this gmail account

Thanks

Comment: Gmail still support SMTP. Have you enabled less secure apps in your Gmail profile?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231489/smtp-exception-failure-sending-mail/32231849#32231849

Comment: Yes I have enabled less secure apps but still returning errors after applying your suggestions, please could you try with this account info ("demo77377@gmail.com" | "AABBCCDDEE1!") cause I feel maybe gmail has effected some changes to their SMTP. Thanks @Equalsk

Comment: I tested this and it worked fine, see the email in your inbox. I have posted the code I used with private details removed.

Answer (score 1):

This code is verified to work fine:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("YOUREMAIL@gmail.com", "YOUREMAIL@gmail.com");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("YOUREMAIL@gmail.com", "YOUREMAIL@gmail.com");
const string fromPassword = "YOURPASSWORD";
const string subject = "YOUREMAIL@gmail.com";
const string body = "YOUREMAIL@gmail.com";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
    Timeout = 20000
};

using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

I'm not comfortable including your personal details even though you have so I have removed them. Obviously replace the email and password with the correct details.

Comment: Confirmed, I saw the email in my inbox but after running your code snippet replacing with correct details, I still get the error "The server response was: connection rejected" and sometimes the error "Server does not support secure connections" but when I comment out enableSsl, I get the error "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain". since the code works from your end, what do you think can be the issue with my system. Thanks @Equalsk

Comment: What version of. NET are you targeting? You may need to enable TLS 1.2 if you're on 4.5 or earlier.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional and my version is .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: TLS 1.2 is only on by default in 4.6. In 4.5 you can switch in on in code or via the registry. This blog has some information http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Comment: Just upgraded console project to ".NET Framework 4.6" but still encountering the same error...what can I do? Thanks @Equalsk

Comment: Who are you sending the mail to? Are you saying it fails when you send it to the same Gmail address as I did? Or are you sending to a different address? There's something you're neglecting to tell me here because the code is not the issue. I have a feeling that whatever domain you're sending to is the problem and not the code or Gmail.

Comment: I am sending the mail to myself

Comment: To the same "demo77377" Gmail you're sending from or a different address?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working after switching from my hotel's wireless network to office network...type of network connection has a role to play in sending email via SMTP in C#